# How to extract map from json string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this json:SBHJm ,./tf,dj kmlhsZdsbnmifgkldsf;kbnrfposfj mfgiofsmkv fgopktmfiosadznjeriosdbnmseroidzjbm iosersj ioz;dknrwfdc iOSRZdfhntfrwaio;dxcmjsterkd0pofg dmfpos mjrsepodhnjsew2gioxhjnmkw2eospjkrepo'd,j-0p]z[tmhjoe[apwtjmdyt,]-9op524RMJNW45OEPNHJM53,94-0WPH5S4RTKL4EJR-903EIK-O0JHYTK2QW]-0MS,UK4Wope0skjdytpof[4r21mwejn9eopwkm5ret-0pyt,k21qom-p[k,tl[]3q,kwqpmjpogtmpol

```
[
  [
    {
      "hasTouchScreen": true,
      "hasTelephoneCommunication": true,
      "braceletType": "METALLIC",
      "sexType": "MALE",
      "isWaterproof": true,
      "id": 20,
      "cost": 4200.5,
      "modelName": "casmod-2",
      "manufacturer": "rolex",
      "clockFaceGlassType": "GLASS"
    },
    1
  ],
  [
    {
      "hasTouchScreen": true,
      "hasTelephoneCommunication": true,
      "braceletType": "METALLIC",
      "sexType": "MALE",
      "isWaterproof": true,
      "id": 21,
      "cost": 5200.0,
      "modelName": "casmod-3",
      "manufacturer": "rolex",
      "clockFaceGlassType": "GLASS"
    },
    1
  ],
  [
    {
      "hasTouchScreen": true,
      "hasTelephoneCommunication": true,
      "braceletType": "METALLIC",
      "sexType": "MALE",
      "isWaterproof": true,
      "id": 22,
      "cost": 300.0,
      "modelName": "casmod-4",
      "manufacturer": "rolex",
      "clockFaceGlassType": "GLASS"
    },
    2
  ]
]
```

How I can get and iterate Map in JQuery? Map is serialized via Gson in java.

Comment: is that the cat-on-keyboard encoding?

Comment: "Gson in java" or do you mean "json in JavaScript"?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let index in map) {...}
```

OR in jQuery

```
$.each(map, function(index, element) {...});
```

[$.each API docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)